# How do i store user input in a variable?

Tags: java

```
    package practiceit;

      import java.util.Scanner;

     public class numbers {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
      int max=0;
     int min = 0;
 }
   public static int smallestLargest() {
   Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in); 
   System.out.print("how many numbers do you want to enter?");
 int num= console.nextInt();
 for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
int nums =console.nextInt();
System.out.println("Number "+i+": "+nums);  
}

return nums; 
}
}
```

How can I return nums so that it is stored as both a max and min variable, so I can print the highest and lowest value typed by the user?

Comment: Are you asking how to invoke a method? You're doing multiple variable assignments and method invocations in your code.

Comment: add the numbers to an array or arraylist

Comment: im not allowed to use arrays, i think the answer is a bit more simple than that

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class numbers
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int min = 0, max = 0, current, nums;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter: ");
    nums = scan.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
    {
        current = scan.nextInt();
        if(i == 0)
        {
            min = current;
            max = current;
        }
        if(current < min)
            min = current;
        if(max < current)
            max = current;
    }
    //after the loop you should have the max and min value the user entered.
    System.out.println("The max number is: "+max);
    System.out.println("The min number is: "+min);
    scan.close();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have all the value in array

```
       package practiceit;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class numbers {
    int[] array = null;
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int max=0;
        int min = 0;
    }
public static int smallestLargest() {
     Scanner console= new Scanner(System.in); 
     System.out.print("how many numbers do you want to enter?");
     int num= console.nextInt();
     array[] = new int[num];
     for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
         int nums =console.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Number "+i+": "+nums); 
         array [i]= nums;
        }
    return nums; 
    }
}
```

If you use `Array.sort(array);`  you will have sorted array and it will be easy to read minimum and maximum value